# how to get value from one table which is not present in another that?

Tags: mysql, yii

i have two table user table and book table.

```
user_id   
1
2
3
4
5
book
user_id book_id
1        1
2        2
4        5
```

i want those record from user table which is not present book table . how should i do that ? i tried this code but is there any  other efficient way ?

```
$cri_user = new CDbCriteria;
        $cri_user->select = "t.user_id";
        $cri_user->condition = "t.user_id NOT IN (select tu.user_id from books as tu group by tu.user_id)";
        $model_user = User::model()->findAll($user);
```

if i get the solution in mysql form i can convert it into yii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some more way to do the same:

**method 1:**

```
$sql = "select t.* from user t left join book b on b.user_id = t.user_id where b.user_id is null";
        $records = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
        print_r($records);
```

**method 2:**

```
$records = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('t.*')
            ->from('user t')
            ->leftJoin('book b', 'b.user_id = t.user_id')
            ->where('b.user_id is null')
            ->queryAll();

        print_r($records);
```

Answer (score 1):

in SQL you can write something like follows,

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM USER 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BOOKS 
                   WHERE USER.USER_ID = BOOKS.USER_ID)
```